# tensorflow checkpoint messageno match with training metric

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I set up checkpoint callback with `checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=ckpt_path, save_best_only=True, monitor='val_auc', verbose=1)`. When I take look at my training log, it seems mismatching.

```
：Epoch 00004: val_auc improved from 0.96440 to 0.96298, saving model to xxxxxxx
py log：2878/2878 - 352s - loss: 0.2071 - tp: 1207371.0000 - fp: 66819.0000 - tn: 1484009.0000 - fn: 187884.0000 - accuracy: 0.9135 - precision: 0.9476 - recall: 0.8653 - auc: 0.9698 - pr: 0.9731 - val_loss: 0.2388 - val_tp: 338551.0000 - val_fp: 5482.0000 - val_tn: 76038.0000 - val_fn: 49446.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.8830 - val_precision: 0.9841 - val_recall: 0.8726 - val_auc: 0.9630 - val_pr: 0.9921
```

Why `val_auc` improved from a bigger one to smaller one, and why it's `0.96298` not `0.9630` in the line below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `mode` parameter to `max` to save the max `val_auc` everytime.

```
checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=ckpt_path, mode="max", save_best_only=True, monitor='val_auc', verbose=1)
```

The documentation for the parameter `mode` explains this:

> mode: one of {'auto', 'min', 'max'}. If `save_best_only=True`, the
> decision to overwrite the current save file is made based on either
> the maximization or the minimization of the monitored quantity.
> For `val_acc`, this should be `max`, for `val_loss` this should be
> `min`, etc. In `auto` mode, the mode is set to `max` if the quantities
> monitored are 'acc' or start with 'fmeasure' and are set to `min` for
> the rest of the quantities.

Since the default value is `auto` and you are monitoring `val_auc` not `acc` or anything that starts with `fmeasure` it is set to `min`.

The `val_auc` in the logs are rounded to 4 decimal places that's why you see it as `0.9630` instead of `0.96298`.